# Get lotus notes logged in user's email in JAVA client

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am writing a lotus note plugin. I want the lotus notes login user email inside the java client. i.e. the email address that user has used to signed in lotus notes. My lotus notes is configured for a Gmail account i.e. I am using a Gmail account to send a mail using lotus notes. 
**Here is my work flow:**
I have created an Action "my action" just at the side of  "send" button inside "Message" form. When i click the "my action" it trigger my JAVA client where i have to get the logged in user email address.

So my question is how to get the login user email?

Answer (score 3):

try to get value from field `INETFrom`.

Notice, there is no difference what langauge you use, java, lotusscript, c++, you just need to know name of item where memo stores Internet address. if you have LN client you can check all fields inside of memo using properties, it may help a lot as well.

Btw, in case if the memo was sent from one Domino user to another Domino user inside one domain (and ofc it depends of settings on Domino server) it could be that there is no information inside of memo about Internet address.

If that does not help, try to check all items with this code (that will print out you all items so you will find where there is an email):

```
Vector items = doc.getItems();
for (int j=0; j<items.size(); j++) {
    Item item = (Item)items.elementAt(j);
    System.out.println(item.getName() + " = " + item.getValueString());
}
```

Comment: Can you give one example of this

Comment: doc.getItemValueString("INETFrom")

Comment: I am using : final Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext(); and then doc.getItemValueString("INETFrom"). but i am getting nothing its blank

Comment: its still not clear where (I guess agent from last line of code) do you take memo document and how you test it. here is my suggestion for you (please read my original post, I've added there couple lines of code you need to run and check items)

Comment: I am sorry as i am new in lotus notes development so am slowly getting your point. What i am doing : I am calling my java agent on an action from inside "Message" form and tried the above code but didn't get any field called "INETFrom". I think this is cos of i am using Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();  instead of "memo document" that you are saying to use. I dont know how can i get the "memo document". I guess cos of this only i am not getting the field "INETFrom". can you please help me out how to get this memo document.

Comment: When you open up your agent in Domino Designer, what do the "
Runtime" properties look like?  I.e., the trigger, the dropdown selection for the agent type, and the dropdown selection for the target?

Answer (score 0):

Since your updated question has now clarified that you are looking for the current logged-in user's email address, and you have specified that the user is a gmail user -- I believe that what you are asking is how to get the user's gmail address.  Is that correct?  If I'm correct, then I believe the answer will be that you must write some code to read the user's current Location document from his personal address book. To verify if I am on the right track, I suggest the following:

- In the Notes client, look at the location section at the right of the status bar at the bottom of the window.  Take note of the location name (e.g., "Office", "Home", etc.) that appears there.
- Click on the location section and select "Edit Locations..." from the pop-up menu.
- In the Select the Locations pane of the Preference dialog, select the name of your location from the list, and click on the Edit button.
- Click on the Basics tab, and check:  Is the address that you want in the field labeled 'Internet mail address'?

Please post the answer to the question in my last bullet point as a new comment. It it is there, then I will continue this answer with further details.

**Previous answer:**

If the message you are reading is a Notes internal message, from one Notes user to another, then the sender's name *is* the email address.  If the sender is a Notes user in your own domain, and you want his Internet email address, then you have to look it up in the Domino Directory.  If you are using Notes/Domino 8 or above, you can use the `LookupNames` method of the `lotus.domino.Directory` class for that in your Java code.

Comment: When i run the following code

Session session = getSession();
Directory dir=session.getDirectory(session.getServerName());
System.out.println("mail info " +dir.getMailInfo(session.getUserName()));

I got the following exception:

 NotesException: User not found in Directory

While i print the value of

session.getUserName()  It returns the username.Why it is like that

Comment: That code works for me.  Add more println calls for session.getServerName() and dir.getServer().  What do you see?  Is it the server that you expect?

Comment: The most obvious answer, though, is that the user ID you are using to run your agent is not in the Domino Directory.  But your question here is NOT about finding the user in the Domino Directory. It is about finding the sender, right?  And of course, that will work only if the sender is a Lotus Notes user in the same domain.

Comment: session.getServerName() and dir.getServer(). both showing nothing. Is it cos of some notes client configuration. I am using Gmail account with my notes client to send email. My plugin will run inside lotus client.I am really not liking this lotus notes.

Comment: It's very important to understand the architecture of Notes/Domino before writing code for it (this is true for getting values from Active Directory as well). Also it's important to be as specific as possible about your question and provide as much information as possible in order to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Yes, if you are set up to use a GMail account to send your mail that probably means you don't have a Domino server set up as your home server.  That means that getSession is establishing a session only for your local client, so getDirectory cannot possibly connect to the Domino Directory on a server.  But the only reason that you would need to connect to the Domino Directory is if you are trying to look up the internetAddress for a Lotus Notes/domino user, and since now you have revealed that you are using the Notes client for Gmail messages, it's obvious that that is not the right solution.

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity. So then what should i do to achieve my goal.

Comment: `Click on the Basics tab, and check: Is the address that you want in the field labeled 'Internet mail address'?` Yes I got the gmail address here it is the address that i want to read inside  my java client. SO please continue..

Comment: It is too late at night for me to continue now.  (I would probably make a lot of mistakes!) But I will try to remember to come back to this sometime tomorrow for you.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz you remember!